# How to change label.Text in asp.net content page on multiple button clicks?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label in a content page that is placed inside a Master page. On multiple button clicks, I want to change the label text on every click. This works fine when I make a simple page without nesting it inside a master page, but when I use this in a content page nested in a master page, the label text doesn't change on multiple clicks.

Here's the code:

```
Label1.Text = " "+ (i++);
```

(`i` is a global variable.)

This was a mockup question for a large problem. Actually I have a large application in which i fetch token numbers from database and display them on labels. When next button is clicked, the next token is to be displayed. Which works fine when i dont add the labels in content page placed in a content page placeholder inside a master page.
Heres the PageLoad Code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LS.Text = Request.QueryString["val"];  
    Label24.Visible = false;
    cnn.ConnectionString = "server=*****;database=****;username=****;password=******;";
    cnn.Open();
    PopulateDataTable();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Label1.Text = ""; // display nothing when page is loaded
        Label2.Text = "";
        Label3.Text = "";
        Label4.Text = "";

        HiddenField1.Value = "0";
        nextButton.Visible = false;
        adjButton.Visible = false;

    }
    if (Request.Form["HiddenField1"] != null)
        rowIndex = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["HiddenField1"].ToString());  

}
```

This is the code for button click event:

```
' protected void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Next Button 
    {

        try
        {
            string query2 = "";

            cnn.Open();
            MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT location from login where user_id='" + LS.Text + "';";
            Cmd.Connection = cnn;
            string location = Cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT counter from login where user_id='" + LS.Text + "' and location = '"+location+"';";
            Cmd.Connection = cnn;
            string counter = Cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            cnn.Close();
            if (counter == "1")
            {
                if (rowIndex == dt.Rows.Count)
                {
                    nextButton.Enabled = false;
                    resetButton.Enabled = false;
                    adjButton.Enabled = false;
                    msgTxt.Visible = true;
                    msgTxt.Text = "The maximum no of tokens for today have been reached.";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
                else if ((dt.Rows.Count > 0) && (rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count))
                {
                    Label1.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                    query2 = "Insert into " + location + "(counter1) value (" + Label1.Text + ") ;";
                }
                else
                {
                    msgTxt.Text = "The maximum no of tokens for today have been reached.";
                }

            }
            else if (counter == "2")
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from " + location + " where counter1 > -1;";
                Cmd.Connection = cnn;
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                cnn.Close();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    if (rowIndex == count)
                    {
                        nextButton.Enabled = false;
                        resetButton.Enabled = false;
                        adjButton.Enabled = false;
                        msgTxt.Visible = true;
                        msgTxt.Text = "No more requests pending.";
                        Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                        //Label1.Font.Strikeout = true;
                    }
                    else if (rowIndex < count)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        Label2.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        query2 = "update " + location + " set counter2=" + Label2.Text + " WHERE counter1=" + Label2.Text + ";";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    msgTxt.Text = "No more requests pending.";
                }

            }
            else if (counter == "3")
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from " + location + " where counter2 > -1;";
                Cmd.Connection = cnn;
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                cnn.Close();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    if (rowIndex == count)
                    {
                        nextButton.Enabled = false;
                        resetButton.Enabled = false;
                        adjButton.Enabled = false;
                        msgTxt.Visible = true;
                        msgTxt.Text = "No more requests pending.";
                        Label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                        //Label1.Font.Strikeout = true;
                    }
                    else if (rowIndex < count)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        Label2.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        Label3.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        query2 = "update " + location + " set counter3=" + Label3.Text + " WHERE counter2=" + Label3.Text + ";";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    msgTxt.Text = "No more requests pending.";
                }

            }
            else if (counter == "4")
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from " + location + " where counter3 > -1;";
                Cmd.Connection = cnn;
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                cnn.Close();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    if (rowIndex == count)
                    {
                        nextButton.Enabled = false;
                        resetButton.Enabled = false;
                        adjButton.Enabled = false;
                        msgTxt.Visible = true;
                        msgTxt.Text = "No more requests pending.";
                        Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                        //Label1.Font.Strikeout = true;
                    }
                    else if (rowIndex < count)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        Label2.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        Label3.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        Label4.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["token_id"].ToString();
                        query2 = "update " + location + " set counter4=" + Label4.Text + " WHERE counter3=" + Label4.Text + ";";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    msgTxt.Text = "No more requests pending.";
                }

            }

            rowIndex++;
            HiddenField1.Value = ""+rowIndex;

            MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query2, cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            da2.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();   

        }
        catch
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }'
```

Comment: Can you post your Page_Load method and Button Click event code and how are you setting initial value to i?

Comment: @rs. This was a mockup question for a large problem. Actually I have a large application in which i fetch token numbers from database and display them on labels. When next button is clicked, the next token is to be displayed. Which works fine when i dont add the labels in content page placed in a content page placeholder inside a master page.
I have added the code by editing the question , kindly have a look

Comment: Where is `rowIndex` defined? What happens if I plugin malicious SQL into the LS textbox? Look into parameterized queries and SQL Injection, *especially* if this is a large application. Not to be too picky either, but you should definitely take all that Data Access out of your UI.

Comment: @ragerory 'rowIndex' is a class variable along with these:
'MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int rowIndex = 0; '

This is basically the Admin Panel, how do I access and control data without the UI ?

Comment: Create a Business Logic Layer that talks to your Data Access, and only allow your UI to talk to your Business Layer. Abstraction is a wonderful thing.

Comment: @ragerory Oh Right ! Will have to change the whole architectural design for that
This is my semester project that is to be submitted day after tomorrow Can you please help me with the label thing, the solution that you posted does not work and I've been stuck here for hours.

Comment: @IffatFatima There is not much I can do here without seeing *all* the code and where the actual error happens. Did you set a breakpoint and step through the code to see where it should be incrementing and why it isn't? There are some simple troubleshooting things you can do, and your comments keep adding extra bits of code not included in the post that are important.

Comment: @ragerory i debugged the code using break points. It increments fine when the UI is in a simple form. As soon as i add it using Content Page, the values don't increment. Anyways Thank you for the help

Comment: Have you tried adding the following to `Page_Load` -- `HiddenField1.Value = rowIndex` right after you set the `rowIndex`? You're only setting it in your `nextButton_Click` handler, which gets fired before your `PostBack`....

Answer (score 0):

Where does `HiddenFieldValue1.Value` get incremented? You're setting `rowIndex` equal to that, but I don't see where it gets incremented, so it looks like it will stay the same.

```
if (Request.Form["HiddenField1"] != null)
    rowIndex = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["HiddenField1"].ToString());
```

Should probably be:

```
if (Request.Form["HiddenField1"] != null)
{
    rowIndex = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["HiddenField1"].ToString());
    HiddenField1.Value = rowIndex;
}
```

Comment: @IffatFatima see the update -- this might be where you're losing it.